# MVC Entity Framework Rollback is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I am tryin to use Transactions in my application which coded in MVC.net
I have my dbcontext in a layer and I reach it from a business layer. When I run the code its not giving me any errors but its also not making the transaction at all.

This is my context

```
public class DB : IDisposable
{
    public DB()
    {


    }

    private RootDYSContext _ctx = null;
    public RootDYSContext ctx
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ctx == null)
                _ctx = new RootDYSContext();
            return _ctx;
        }
        set
        {
            _ctx = value;
        }
    }
    public bool Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Mesaj = exp.Message;
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

And this is how I am tryin to do transaction which based on here "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions"

```
    public bool CreateKullanici(VMKullanici 
    KullaniciData,List<VMRol>RolDataList,VMRol AnaRolData)
    {
        string mesaj = "";
        int kullanici_id;

        using (RootDBHelper.DB db = new RootDBHelper.DB())
        {

            using (var ctx = new RootDBLayer.RootDYSContext())
            {
                using (DbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction = 
                   ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        kullanici_id = SaveKullanici(KullaniciData, out 
                   mesaj);
                        foreach(VMRol rol in RolDataList)
                        {
                            VMKullaniciRol KullaniciRolInsertData = new 
                                  VMKullaniciRol();
                            KullaniciRolInsertData.kullanici_id = 
                              kullanici_id;
                            KullaniciRolInsertData.rol_id = rol.rol_id;

                            if (rol.rol_id == AnaRolData.rol_id)
                                KullaniciRolInsertData.ana_rol_mu = 
                                   (int)RConstants.EvetHayir.Evet;
                            else
                                KullaniciRolInsertData.ana_rol_mu = 
                             (int)RConstants.EvetHayir.Hayir;


                bKullaniciRol.SaveKullaniciRol(KullaniciRolInsertData, out mesaj);
                        }
/*Edit:I think this line made confusion I put this to make sure rollback 
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); */
                     dbContextTransaction.Commit();

                        return true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect when I run this I shouldnt get any record at all.I seriously stucked because I dont get any error or any hint at all and this method keeps saving data regardless of rollback.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: I do my save changes part on the insert methods 
Adding also code examples for the methods

```
    public int SaveKullanici(VMKullanici KullaniciData, out string mesaj)
    {
        using (RootDBHelper.DB db = new RootDBHelper.DB())
        {
            mesaj = "";
            PKullanici pKullanici = new PKullanici();
            if (KullaniciData.kullanici_id == default(int))
                pKullanici.InsertKullanici(db.ctx, KullaniciData);
            else
                pKullanici.UpdateKullanici(db.ctx, KullaniciData);
            if (db.Commit())
            {
                return KullaniciData.kullanici_id;
            }
            else
            {
                mesaj = db.Mesaj;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }



    public void InsertKullanici(RootDYSContext ctx, VMKullanici KullaniciData)
    {
        ctx.TKullanici.Add(KullaniciData.TKullanici);
    }
```

Comment: The issue isn't with the BCL, there is something else wrong that we cant see, `dbContextTransaction.Commit();` will commit and `dbContextTransaction.Rollback();` will roll back under these circumstances

Comment: If you commit there is no way to rollback

Comment: Where you calling `dbContext.SaveChanges`? May be somewhere you are using different context to save the changes, expecting rollback on the outer function to rollback the transaction.

Comment: @RajN looks like in here   bKullaniciRol.SaveKullaniciRol(KullaniciRolInsertData, out mesaj);

Comment: What's a _Kullanici_ ?

Comment: Looks like Turkish word probably user or consumer

Comment: @thepirat000 just an object for user with types of db elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you do commit and then you want to rollback but you should one thing commit or rollback.

In addition I cant see in your code where you actually doing transaction.commit. Your code has commit function but commit != savechanges.

Idea of transactions (there are different type but) is that you save data to database do some validation or operations and then you say well it looks ok commit or there is an error do rollback.

Also note if you are not do not commit or do rollback then your identity field will get incremented no matter what

Comment: thanks I added other methods which I used on example so it can be more clear now I do my save changes also when I was posting this I changed commit part on purpose. Because at the end of code execution I expect no record on database. That was my aim.

Comment: @BeytulKocakaplan now it looks correct. Also calling rollback is same as NOT calling commit

Comment: @BeytulKocakaplan so basically saying what is your problem now? Code is messy but it should work as expected

Comment: Well it is not working it is the problem even tho it goes in catch block its not rolling back db values.

Comment: @BeytulKocakaplan How do you know? and which error you is there?

Comment: Well I send not null value as null on second insert it should be terminated and rollback first insert also but it does not inserts first record and not second.